# Unexpected token: void (processing)

Tags: java, processing

I keep getting this

> unexpected token: void

in my set up as shown below.

```java
public static void main (String[] args)
{

    MenuBar me = new MenuBar();
    me.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    me.setVisible(true);

    void setup()
    {
        size(640, 640);
        H.init(this).background(#202020);
        smooth();

        colors = new HColorPool(#9400D3, #FFE4E1, #FFE4B5, #FFDAB9, #A9A9A9, #FA8072, #D2B48C, #C0C0C0);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You're missing closing brackets:

```java
public static void main (String[] args)
{
  MenuBar me = new MenuBar();
  me.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  me.setVisible(true);
} //here

void setup()
{
  size(640, 640);
  H.init(this).background(#202020);
  smooth();
  colors = new HColorPool(#9400D3, #FFE4E1, #FFE4B5, #FFDAB9, #A9A9A9, #FA8072, #D2B48C, #C0C0C0);
} //and here
```

Comment: Thank you. The program builds with no errors just does not run :(

Comment: @BethannyJane You're going to have to be more specific. Can you post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Have you tried adding print statements to figure out what's going on? You might be better off asking a separate question.